# Creating Multidimensional arrays and interpolating in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 8 arrays, when each one is plotted it gives 'x Vs. Detection Probability'. I want to combine these arrays so that I can perform a multidimensional interpolation to find the detection probability from variables in each of the dimensions.

Here are a couple of my arrays as an example.

```
In [3]: mag_rec
Out[3]:
array([[  1.35000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
   [  1.38333333e+01,   5.38461538e-01],
   [  1.41666667e+01,   5.84158416e-01],
   [  1.45000000e+01,   6.93771626e-01],
   [  1.48333333e+01,   7.43629344e-01],
   [  1.51666667e+01,   8.30774480e-01],
   [  1.55000000e+01,   8.74700571e-01],
   [  1.58333333e+01,   8.84866920e-01],
   [  1.61666667e+01,   8.95135908e-01],
   [  1.65000000e+01,   8.97150997e-01],
   [  1.68333333e+01,   8.90416846e-01],
   [  1.71666667e+01,   8.90911598e-01],
   [  1.75000000e+01,   8.90111460e-01],
   [  1.78333333e+01,   8.89567069e-01],
   [  1.81666667e+01,   8.82184730e-01],
   [  1.85000000e+01,   8.76020265e-01],
   [  1.88333333e+01,   8.54947843e-01],
   [  1.91666667e+01,   8.43505477e-01],
   [  1.95000000e+01,   8.24739363e-01],
   [  1.98333333e+01,   7.70070922e-01],
   [  2.01666667e+01,   6.33006993e-01],
   [  2.05000000e+01,   4.45367502e-01],
   [  2.08333333e+01,   2.65029636e-01],
   [  2.11666667e+01,   1.22023390e-01],
   [  2.15000000e+01,   4.02201524e-02],
   [  2.18333333e+01,   1.51190986e-02],
   [  2.21666667e+01,   8.75088215e-03],
   [  2.25000000e+01,   4.39466969e-03],
   [  2.28333333e+01,   3.65476525e-03]])
```

and

```
In [5]: lmt_mag
Out[5]:
array([[ 16.325     ,   0.35      ],
   [ 16.54166667,   0.39583333],
   [ 16.75833333,   0.35555556],
   [ 16.975     ,   0.29666667],
   [ 17.19166667,   0.42222222],
   [ 17.40833333,   0.38541667],
   [ 17.625     ,   0.4875    ],
   [ 17.84166667,   0.41956242],
   [ 18.05833333,   0.45333333],
   [ 18.275     ,   0.45980392],
   [ 18.49166667,   0.46742424],
   [ 18.70833333,   0.4952381 ],
   [ 18.925     ,   0.49423077],
   [ 19.14166667,   0.53375   ],
   [ 19.35833333,   0.56239316],
   [ 19.575     ,   0.52217391],
   [ 19.79166667,   0.55590909],
   [ 20.00833333,   0.57421227],
   [ 20.225     ,   0.5729304 ],
   [ 20.44166667,   0.61708204],
   [ 20.65833333,   0.63968037],
   [ 20.875     ,   0.65627395],
   [ 21.09166667,   0.66177885],
   [ 21.30833333,   0.69375   ],
   [ 21.525     ,   0.67083333],
   [ 21.95833333,   0.88333333],
   [ 22.175     ,   0.85833333]])
```

How, in Python, would I go about combining these arrays into a multidimensional array? (More arrays will have to be included)

Further to this, once I have this multidimensional array, is `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates` the fastest way to interpolate on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate your arrays with [`numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) 
and for redimension `numpy` have some different function [HERE](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#changing-number-of-dimensions) that you can use them depending on your need !

e.g Demo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = np.array([[5, 6]])
>>> np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

>>> np.expand_dims(y, axis=0)
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]]])
>>> np.expand_dims(y, axis=2)
array([[[1],
        [2]],

       [[3],
        [4]],

       [[5],
        [6]]])
```